# Error while compiling Thrift Server

Tags: c++, thrift

I am new to Thrift : http://thrift.apache.org/
I am using CentOS, and "maybe" install Thrift succesfully. I  can use thrift to generate codes.
But Follow the instruction: http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageC%2B%2B
I get the Error  while compile the Something_server.cpp
Someone know pls help me to find out the reason. I have no idea. Thank you very much

I use thrift to let PHP to call C++ to do a job that only C++ can do. 
Any one have another suggestion for me ? Thank you

> [root@localhost gen-cpp]# g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/thrift *.cpp -lthrift -o something
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc: In member function âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT::writeI16(int16_t)â:
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc:147: error: there are no arguments to âhtonsâ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of âhtonsâ must be available
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc:147: error: (if you use â-fpermissiveâ, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc: In member function âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT::writeI32(int32_t)â:
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc:154: error: there are no arguments to âhtonlâ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of âhtonlâ must be available
>   Something_server.cpp: In member function âvirtual int32_t SomethingHandler::ping()â:
>   Something_server.cpp:28: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc: In member function âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT::writeI16(int16_t) [with Transport_ = apache::thrift::transport::TTransport]â:
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TVirtualProtocol.h:401:   instantiated from âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TVirtualProtocol::writeI16_virt(int16_t) [with Protocol_ = apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT, Super_ = apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolDefaults]â
>   Something_server.cpp:42:   instantiated from here
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc:147: error: âhtonsâ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc: In member function âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT::writeI32(int32_t) [with Transport_ = apache::thrift::transport::TTransport]â:
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TVirtualProtocol.h:405:   instantiated from âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TVirtualProtocol::writeI32_virt(int32_t) [with Protocol_ = apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT, Super_ = apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolDefaults]â
>   Something_server.cpp:42:   instantiated from here
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc:154: error: âhtonlâ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc: In member function âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT::readI16(int16_t&) [with Transport_ = apache::thrift::transport::TTransport]â:
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TVirtualProtocol.h:499:   instantiated from âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TVirtualProtocol::readI16_virt(int16_t&) [with Protocol_ = apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT, Super_ = apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolDefaults]â
>   Something_server.cpp:42:   instantiated from here
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc:362: error: ântohsâ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc: In member function âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT::readI32(int32_t&) [with Transport_ = apache::thrift::transport::TTransport]â:
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TVirtualProtocol.h:503:   instantiated from âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TVirtualProtocol::readI32_virt(int32_t&) [with Protocol_ = apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT, Super_ = apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolDefaults]â
>   Something_server.cpp:42:   instantiated from here
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc:373: error: ântohlâ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc: In member function âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT::writeI16(int16_t)â:
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc:147: error: there are no arguments to âhtonsâ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of âhtonsâ must be available
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc:147: error: (if you use â-fpermissiveâ, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc: In member function âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT::writeI32(int32_t)â:
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc:154: error: there are no arguments to âhtonlâ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of âhtonlâ must be available
>   Something_server.skeleton.cpp: In member function âvirtual int32_t SomethingHandler::ping()â:
>   Something_server.skeleton.cpp:28: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc: In member function âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT::writeI16(int16_t) [with Transport_ = apache::thrift::transport::TTransport]â:
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TVirtualProtocol.h:401:   instantiated from âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TVirtualProtocol::writeI16_virt(int16_t) [with Protocol_ = apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT, Super_ = apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolDefaults]â
>   Something_server.skeleton.cpp:42:   instantiated from here
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc:147: error: âhtonsâ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc: In member function âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT::writeI32(int32_t) [with Transport_ = apache::thrift::transport::TTransport]â:
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TVirtualProtocol.h:405:   instantiated from âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TVirtualProtocol::writeI32_virt(int32_t) [with Protocol_ = apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT, Super_ = apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolDefaults]â
>   Something_server.skeleton.cpp:42:   instantiated from here
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc:154: error: âhtonlâ was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.tcc: In member function âuint32_t apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT::readI16(int16_t&) [with Transport_ = apache::thrift::transport::TTransport]â:

Comment: I am in the same boat - CentOS, Thrift build from source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems as though you have a problem with htons(), htonl() functions missing, have you included the correct header?

`#include <arpa/inet.h>`

Answer (score 5):

On my system (Ubuntu 10.10), htons() and htonl() are declared in netinet/in.h.

I had the same error, and I fixed it by adding -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H to the g++ command line parameters when building my Thrift server.

This will cause the preprocessor to include netinet/in.h in thrift/protocol/TPrototol.h, so the hton* declarations will be visible to the compiler.

TProtocol.h has the following lines which cause the compiler error when HAVE_NETINET_IN_H is not defined.

```
#ifdef HAVE_NETINET_IN_H
#include <netinet/in.h>
#endif
```

This might be a bug in the Thrift configure script which somehow skips the define.

Answer (score 1):

From [Gmane](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.thrift.user/2353) you need a few #defines.
Add in `-DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H` to your Makefile.

Eg. In the Makefile

```
BOOST_DIR = /usr/include/boost
THRIFT_DIR = /usr/local/include/thrift
LIB_DIR = /usr/local/lib
BOOST_LIB_DIR = /usr/lib64/boost
THRIFT_LIB_DIR = /home/timothy.ohare/bin/lib

g++ -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H -o CppServer -I${THRIFT_DIR} -I${BOOST_DIR}  -I../gen-cpp -L${LIB_DIR}  -L${BOOST_LIB_DIR}  -L${THRIFT_LIB_DIR} -lthrift CppServer.cpp ${GEN_SRC}
```